# Why am I not getting any output when I convert my code into an executable and run it?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to write a code that lists out the names of the countries reported by
2022 World Happiness Report ranked by the happiness index, given in HTML format via this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report?action=raw and my response is supposed to be:

```
Finland
Norway
Denmark
Iceland
Switzerland
Netherlands
```

As you can see from the link I've attached, I noticed a pattern that all the countries have one thing in common, which is that they are within 2 square brackets [[ country names ]], so I decided to use `awk` to help me out like this:

```
echo "$input" | awk 'BEGIN{RS="[[ *]]"} NR>1'
```

However, there seems to be an issue since my code wouldn't run, any suggestions on what should I fix or how to approach this problem?

Comment: Start by just outputting the `data` itself: `echo "data = >>$data<<"` Note the delimiters, which tells you about things like leading or trailing space, including newlines. Do the same for `content` and `filtered_content`. As for `filtered_content` split up the pipeline into smaller parts, so you can see the output of each pipe.

Comment: You may be able to simplify your pipeline to a single awk. Something like `curl -s yourURL | awk -F'|' '/=== 2022 report ===/{f=1}f==1&&/^\|[0-9]/{i++; if(f==1&&i<11){gsub("}",""); print $NF}}'`. That said, your expected output seems to differ from the data for 2022. For instance, Canada is not listed in the 10 happiest countries in the raw data for 2022 from the link you provided.

Comment: that first `sed` script (`sed -n '/^| {{flag|/p'`) doesn't generate anything for me; I'd suggest manually stepping through each command to verify code accuracy (eg, `echo "$content"`, then `echo "$content" | sed -n '/^| {{flag|/p'`, then `echo "$content" | sed -n '/^| {{flag|/p' | sed -e 's/^| {{flag|//g' -e 's/}}//g'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you organized your code is slightly off. I've played around with your code a bit and I'd recommend using `grep` to filter out data which contains any lowercase or uppercase alphabets within the enclosed square brackets, since it's a distinct characteristic of the countries mentioned. Something like `grep -E '^[A-Za-z ]+$'` should be useful for your cause.

I'll leave it to you to figure out where and how to implement the code. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your `sed` commands have a space before `{{flag`.
When I tried running your commands, there were no spaces before the curly brackets in the output.

Removing the spaces in the command *almost* works, some countries have some extra data on their line. You can trim this by adding for example a `cut`. So your final line would be:

```
filtered_content=$(echo "$content" | sed -n '/^|{{flag|/p' | sed -e 's/^|{{flag|//g' -e 's/}}//g' | cut -d '|' -f1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't solve everything, but at least it's down to just the list of nations : (unfortunately I couldn't get it to work without that extra `gcat -`)

```
curl -s -L 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report?action=raw' | 

gcat - | 

mawk2 '/^[|].+[{]+[Ff]lag[|][^}]+[}][}][*]*$|=== (19|20)[0-9][0-9] [^=]+ ===/'
```

---

```
     1  === 2023 World Happiness Report ===
     2  === 2022 World Happiness Report ===
     3  === 2021 World Happiness Report ===
     4  === 2020 World Happiness Report ===
     5  === 2019 World Happiness Report ===
     6  === 2018 World Happiness Report ===
     7  === 2017 World Happiness Report ===
     8  === 2016 World Happiness Report ===
     9  === 2015 World Happiness Report ===
    10  === 2013 World Happiness Report ===
    11  === 2012 World Happiness Report ===
    12  === 2023 report ===
    13  |1||{{flag|Finland}}
    14  |2||{{flag|Denmark}}
    15  |3||{{flag|Iceland}}
    16  |4||{{flag|Israel}}
    17  |5||{{flag|Netherlands}}
    18  |6||{{flag|Sweden}}
    19  |7||{{flag|Norway}}
    20  |8||{{flag|Switzerland}}
    21  |9||{{flag|Luxembourg}}
    22  |10||{{flag|New Zealand}}
    23  |11||{{flag|Austria}}
    24  |12||{{flag|Australia}}
    25  |13||{{Flag|Canada}}
    26  |14||{{Flag|Ireland}}
    27  |15||{{flag|United States}}
    28  |16||{{flag|Germany}}
    29  |17||{{flag|Belgium}}
    30  |18||{{flag|Czech Republic}}
    31  |19||{{flag|United Kingdom}}
    32  |20||{{flag|Lithuania}}
    33  |21||{{flag|France}}
    34  |22||{{flag|Slovenia}}
    35  |23||{{flag|Costa Rica}}
    36  |24||{{flag|Romania}}
    37  |25||{{flag|Singapore}}*
    38  |26||{{flag|United Arab Emirates}}
    39  |27||{{flag|Taiwan}}
    40  |28||{{flag|Uruguay}}
    41  |29||{{flag|Slovakia}}*
    42  |30||{{flag|Saudi Arabia}}
    43  |31||{{flag|Estonia}}
    44  |32||{{flag|Spain}}
    45  |33||{{flag|Italy}}
    46  |34||{{flag|Kosovo}}
    47  |35||{{flag|Chile}}
    48  |36||{{flag|Mexico}}
    49  |37||{{flag|Malta}}
    50  |38||{{flag|Panama}}
    51  |39||{{flag|Poland}}
    52  |40||{{flag|Nicaragua}}
    53  |41||{{flag|Latvia}}
    54  |42||{{flag|Bahrain}}*
    55  |43||{{flag|Guatemala}}
    56  |44||{{flag|Kazakhstan}}
    57  |45||{{flag|Serbia}}*
    58  |46||{{flag|Cyprus}}
    59  |47||{{flag|Japan}}
    60  |48||{{flag|Croatia}}
    61  |49||{{flag|Brazil}}
    62  |50||{{flag|El Salvador}}
    63  |51||{{flag|Hungary}}
    64  |52||{{flag|Argentina}}
    65  |53||{{flag|Honduras}}
    66  |54||{{flag|Uzbekistan}}
    67  |55||{{flag|Malaysia}}*
    68  |56||{{flag|Portugal}}
    69  |57||{{flag|South Korea}}
    70  |58||{{flag|Greece}}
    71  |59||{{flag|Mauritius}}
    72  |60||{{flag|Thailand}}
    73  |61||{{flag|Mongolia}}
    74  |62||{{flag|Kyrgyzstan}}
    75  |63||{{flag|Moldova}}
    76  |64||{{flag|China}}*
    77  |65||{{flag|Vietnam}}
    78  |66||{{flag|Paraguay}}
    79  |67||{{flag|Montenegro}}*
    80  |68||{{flag|Jamaica}}
    81  |69||{{flag|Bolivia}}
    82  |70||{{flag|Russia}}
    83  |71||{{flag|Bosnia and Herzegovina}}*
    84  |72||{{flag|Colombia}}
    85  |73||{{flag|Dominican Republic}}
    86  |74||{{flag|Ecuador}}
    87  |75||{{flag|Peru}}
    88  |76||{{flag|Philippines}}*
    89  |77||{{flag|Bulgaria}}
    90  |78||{{flag|Nepal}}
    91  |79||{{flag|Armenia}}
    92  |80||{{flag|Tajikistan}}*
    93  |81||{{flag|Algeria}}*
    94  |82||{{flag|Hong Kong}}
    95  |83||{{flag|Albania}}
    96  |84||{{flag|Indonesia}}
    97  |85||{{flag|South Africa}}*
    98  |86||{{flag|Congo, Republic of}}
    99  |87||{{flag|North Macedonia}}
   100  |88||{{flag|Venezuela}}
   101  |89||{{flag|Laos}}*
   102  |90||{{flag|Georgia}}
   103  |91||{{flag|Guinea}}
   104  |92||{{flag|Ukraine}}
   105  |93||{{flag|Ivory Coast}}
   106  |94||{{flag|Gabon}}
   107  |95||{{flag|Nigeria}}*
   108  |96||{{flag|Cameroon}}
   109  |97||{{flag|Mozambique}}
   110  |98||{{flag|Iraq}}*
   111  |99||{{flag|Palestine}}
   112  |100||{{flag|Morocco}}
   113  |101||{{flag|Iran}}
   114  |102||{{flag|Senegal}}
   115  |103||{{flag|Mauritania}}
   116  |104||{{flag|Burkina Faso}}*
   117  |105||{{flag|Namibia}}
   118  |106||{{flag|Turkey}}*
   119  |107||{{flag|Ghana}}
   120  |108||{{flag|Pakistan}}
   121  |109||{{flag|Niger}}
   122  |110||{{flag|Tunisia}}
   123  |111||{{flag|Kenya}}
   124  |112||{{flag|Sri Lanka}}*
   125  |113||{{flag|Uganda}}*
   126  |114||{{flag|Chad}}
   127  |115||{{flag|Cambodia}}
   128  |116||{{flag|Benin}}
   129  |117||{{flag|Myanmar}}*
   130  |118||{{flag|Bangladesh}}
   131  |119||{{flag|Gambia}}
   132  |120||{{flag|Mali}}
   133  |121||{{flag|Egypt}}
   134  |122||{{flag|Togo}}
   135  |123||{{flag|Jordan}}
   136  |124||{{flag|Ethiopia}}
   137  |125||{{flag|Liberia}}
   138  |126||{{flag|India}}
   139  |127||{{flag|Madagascar}}
   140  |128||{{flag|Zambia}}*
   141  |129||{{flag|Tanzania}}
   142  |130||{{flag|Comoros}}
   143  |131||{{flag|Malawi}}
   144  |132||{{flag|Botswana}}
   145  |133||{{flag|Congo, Democratic Republic of}}
   146  |134||{{flag|Zimbabwe}}
   147  |135||{{flag|Sierra Leone}}
   148  |136||{{flag|Lebanon}}
   149  |137||{{flag|Afghanistan}}
   150  === 2022 report ===
   151  |1||{{flag|Finland}}
   152  |2||{{flag|Denmark}}
   153  |3||{{flag|Iceland}}
   154  |4||{{flag|Switzerland}}
   155  |5||{{flag|Netherlands}}
   156  |6||{{flag|Luxembourg}}
   157  |7||{{flag|Sweden}}
   158  |8||{{flag|Norway}}
   159  |9||{{flag|Israel}}
   160  |10||{{flag|New Zealand}}
   161  |11||{{flag|Austria}}
   162  |12||{{flag|Australia}}
   163  |13||{{Flag|Ireland}}
   164  |14||{{Flag|Germany}}
   165  |15||{{flag|Canada}}
   166  |16||{{flag|United States}}
   167  |17||{{flag|United Kingdom}}
   168  |18||{{flag|Czech Republic}}
   169  |19||{{flag|Belgium}}
   170  |20||{{flag|France}}
   171  === 2020 report ===
   172  |{{flag|Uruguay}}
   173  |{{flag|Saudi Arabia}}
   174  |{{flag|Spain}}
   175  |{{flag|Guatemala}}
   176  |{{flag|Italy}}
   177  |{{flag|Singapore}}
   178  |{{flag|Brazil}}
   179  |{{Flag|Poland}}
   180  |{{Flag|Colombia}}
   181  |{{Flag|Cyprus}}
   182  |{{Flag|Nicaragua}}
   183  |{{Flag|Romania}}
   184  |{{Flag|Kuwait}}
   185  |{{Flag|Mauritius}}
   186  |{{Flag|Kazakhstan}}
   187  |{{Flag|Estonia}}
   188  |{{flag|Jamaica}}
   189  |{{flag|South Korea}}
   190  |{{flag|Japan}}
   191  |{{flag|Peru}}
   192  |{{flag|Serbia}}
   193  |{{flag|Bolivia}}
   194  |{{Flag|Pakistan}}
   195  |{{Flag|Paraguay}}
   196  |{{flag|Dominican Republic}}
   197  |{{flag|Bosnia and Herzegovina}}
   198  |{{flag|Moldova}}
   199  |{{flag|Tajikistan}}
   200  |{{flag|Montenegro}}
   201  |{{flag|Russia}}
   202  |{{flag|Kyrgyzstan}}
   203  |{{flag|Belarus}}
   204  |{{flag|North Cyprus}}
   205  |{{flag|Greece}}
   206  |{{flag|Hong Kong}}
   207  |{{flag|Croatia}}
   208  |{{flag|Gabon}}
   209  |{{flag|South Africa}}
   210  |{{flag|Iraq}}
   211  |{{flag|Lebanon}}
   212  |{{flag|Burkina Faso}}
   213  |{{flag|Gambia}}
   214  |{{flag|Mali}}
   215  |{{flag|Nigeria}}
   216  |{{flag|Eswatini}}
   217  |{{flag|Myanmar}}
   218  |{{flag|Comoros}}
   219  |{{flag|Togo}}
   220  |{{flag|Ethiopia}}
   221  |{{flag|Madagascar}}
   222  |{{flag|Egypt}}
   223  |{{flag|Sierra Leone}}
   224  |{{flag|Burundi}}
   225  |{{flag|Zambia}}
   226  |{{flag|Haiti}}
   227  |{{flag|Lesotho}}
   228  |{{flag|India}}
   229  |{{flag|Malawi}}
   230  |{{flag|Yemen}}
   231  |{{flag|Botswana}}
   232  |{{flag|Tanzania}}
   233  |{{flag|Central African Republic}}
   234  |{{flag|Rwanda}}
   235  |{{flag|Zimbabwe}}
   236  |{{flag|South Sudan}}
   237  |{{flag|Afghanistan}}
   238  === 2019 report ===
   239  === 2013 report ===
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain I understand what you're trying to achieve, especially with the `sort`, the way I understand it that list already comes sorted from "happiest" to "least happy".

You also don't seem to have a good handle on what your data actually looks like - you're trying to define an awk-range, but the string `=== 2021 report ===` doesn't feature in `curl`'s output anywhere.

So, for the top-5 happiest countries in 2022 all you need should be this:

```
curl -s https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report?action=raw | awk '/=== 2022 report ===/,/=== 2020 report ===/'| awk -F'[|}]' '$2~/[0-9]+/{print $5}'| head -n5
Finland
Denmark
Iceland
Switzerland
Netherlands
```